# N Choose K function in R not working--what am I missing?

Tags: r

I was trying to acquaint myself with R's nChooseK function but I can't get it to work. I thought it was part of the standard setup (i.e. no additional package needed).

Please help. Here is what I tried:

```
> nChooseK(10,2) 
  Error: could not find function "nChooseK"
> n<-4;k<-2
> print(nChooseK(n,k)) 
 Error in print(nChooseK(n, k)) : could not find function "nChooseK"
```

the last one was an example I saw here: [R basic nChooseK](http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISdidactique/Rhelp/library/R.basic/html/nChooseK.html)

Comment: and as usual if you have no idea what package it's in you can (usually) use `library(sos); findFn("nChooseK")` (although this only finds it if it's on CRAN, not R-forge, Bioconductor etc.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As joran mentions the function `nChooseK` is a part of R.basic.  You can tell this from the example you posted by looking at the top of the page:

---

[image: Rbasic Page]

---

You'll notice the "R.basic" in the curley braces which tells you that that function is a part of the "R.basic" package.  So to use `nChooseK` you'll first need to load that package

```
library(R.basic)
```

If you don't have R.basic installed yet then you'll need to install it

```
install.packages("R.basic", contriburl="http://www.braju.com/R/repos/")
library(R.basic)
```

But as noted the `choose` function in base R does the same thing

```
choose(37, 12)
#[1] 1852482996
nChooseK(37, 12)
#[1] 1852482996
```

Answer (score 16):

The function is in the **R.basic** package which is not part of the default R installation. You probably meant to use just `choose()`.